# Cannot access a disposed object in a function returns List?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, f#

I have the following function to list all the objects in an S3 folder.

```
let listObjects bucketName prefix =
    try
        use client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast2)
        let request = new ListObjectsV2Request(BucketName = bucketName, MaxKeys = 1000, Prefix = prefix)

        let rec getKeys() = asyncSeq {
            let! response = client.ListObjectsV2Async(request) |> Async.AwaitTask // Error
            for entry in response.S3Objects do
                yield entry.Key
            if response.IsTruncated then yield! getKeys()
            }

        getKeys() |> AsyncSeq.toList
    with
    | :? AmazonS3Exception as s3ex ->
        Log.Error("S3 error occurred. Exception: {0}", s3ex)
        List.empty
    | ex ->
        Log.Error("Exception: {0}\n{1}", ex.Message, ex)
        List.empty
```

However, it got the error on the line `let! response = client.ListObjectsV2Async(request) |> Async.AwaitTask`.

> Unhandled Exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client'.
>      at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.ThrowIfDisposed()
>      at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.InvokeAsync[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, IMarshaller`2 marshaller, ResponseUnmarshaller unmarshaller, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.ListObjectsV2Async(ListObjectsV2Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

---

The following code calling `Dispose()` explicitly works.

```
let listObjects bucketName prefix =
    let client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast2)
    try
        try
            let request = new ListObjectsV2Request(BucketName = bucketName, MaxKeys = 1000, Prefix = prefix)
            let rec getKeys() = asyncSeq {
                let! response = client.ListObjectsV2Async(request) |> Async.AwaitTask
                for entry in response.S3Objects do
                    yield entry.Key
                if response.IsTruncated then yield! getKeys()
                }
            getKeys() |> AsyncSeq.toList
        with
        | :? AmazonS3Exception as s3ex ->
            Log.Error("S3 error occurred. Exception: {0}", s3ex)
            List.empty
        | ex ->
            Log.Error("Exception: {0}\n{1}", ex.Message, ex)
            List.empty
    finally
        client.Dispose()
```

Comment: Looking at the [AsyncSeq source](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq/blob/97113ebcaf30eaf4a5b7d51420292d4e989c9bd9/src/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq/AsyncSeq.fs#L1315), `toList` is implemented via `Async.RunSynchronously()`. So the entire seq should have been consumed before the `AmazonS3Client` instance was disposed by going out of scope. AFAICT, this shouldn't happen, and this might be a bug. I might be wrong, though; let's see what others think.

Comment: You might also try an explicit `.Dispose()` call, which is usually an anti-pattern, just to see if it changes the behavior. E.g., change `use client = ...` to `let client = ...`, then do `let result = getKeys() |> AsyncSeq.toList`, next line `client.Dispose()`, next line `result` at the end of your function. Does that get rid of the ObjectDisposedException?

Comment: I tried explicit `.Dispose()` call and it works. I've added the working one at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question, but I think that the way you are combining asynchronous sequences with synchronous code is not actually giving you any benefits. Asynchronous sequences are useful if you want to write code that will iterate over data coming from some asynchronous data source without blocking, but if you just end up converting your sequence to a list, then there is no point in using asynchronous sequences.

A better approach that might actually solve your problem would be to change the `listObjects` function so that it itself returns an asynchronous sequence. Then you can use the `use` construct inside the async sequence and the computation expression should take care of disposing of the object only after the sequence has been fully iterated:

```
let listObjects bucketName prefix = asyncSeq {
    try
        use client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast2)
        let request = 
            new ListObjectsV2Request(BucketName = bucketName, MaxKeys = 1000, Prefix = prefix)
        let rec getKeys() = asyncSeq {
            let! response = client.ListObjectsV2Async(request) |> Async.AwaitTask 
            for entry in response.S3Objects do
                yield entry.Key
            if response.IsTruncated then yield! getKeys() }

        yield! getKeys()
    with
    | :? AmazonS3Exception as s3ex ->
        Log.Error("S3 error occurred. Exception: {0}", s3ex)
    | ex ->
        Log.Error("Exception: {0}\n{1}", ex.Message, ex)  }
```

If you really need to make things synchronous, you can then call `AsyncSeq.toList` on the result of the function:

```
listObjects "whatever" "prefix" |> AsyncSeq.toList
```

That said, I'm not sure this will actually solve your problem. I think your code should work as is and I'm not quite sure how the behaviour could be caused by a bug in asynchronous sequences. So my guess is that there is something else, elsewhere in your code, that is causing the error.

**EDIT** I just tried if I can reproduce this behaviour without all the references that your code requires, so I adapted it to just iterate over lists and print when the object is disposed. Here is my code:

```
let listObjects () =
  try
    use client = { new IDisposable with member x.Dispose() = printfn "bye" }
    let rec getKeys n = asyncSeq {
        let! nn = Async.Sleep(1)
        for i in 0 .. 1 do yield i
        if n <> 0 then yield! getKeys(n-1) 
        else printfn "completed" }
    printfn "getting"
    getKeys 5 |> AsyncSeq.toList
  with
  | ex ->
      printfn "nop"
      List.empty

listObjects ()
```

This does the right thing - it prints "getting", "completed" and then "bye", so unless I changed something significant accidentally, it looks like `asyncSeq` does the right thing here.

Can you perhaps try adding similar `use` and `printf` to your code, just to check that the behaviour is the same in your case?

Comment: My original code was the same as yours. It got the exception so I added the toList to debug.

Comment: @ca9163d9 That's strange. What happens if you make this completely synchronous? If the error persists after you make it just ordinary synchronous piece of code, then I'm pretty sure the error is elsewhere.

Comment: I tried explicit `.Dispose()` call and it works. I've added the working one at the end of the question. It's ugly and anti-pattern though.

Comment: @ca9163d9 I tried reproducing your error with simpler code snippet, but it works as I'd expect - see the edit.

Comment: I tried to update the code to print the messages but got the error of `The method 'Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.Dispose() : unit' is sealed and cannot be overridden` in the code `{new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast2) with member x.Dispose() = printfn "Dispose" }`.

Comment: @ca9163d9 I was not thinking of adding `{new AmazonS3Client ...`, but rather, just adding another `use` with the exact same `{new IDisposable` to test when it gets called